# Как переписать Template deduction guide (С++17) на C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Дан код на С++17:

```
template<class T>
struct Ok {
    T value;
};
template<> struct Ok<void> {};

// template deduction guides
template<class T> Ok(T) -> Ok<T>;
```

Template deduction guides позволяют имея тип `Ok<T>` вызывать `Ok` как функцию (так выглядит, на самом деле вызывается конструктор):

```
auto c = Ok(5); // T deduced as int
// без template deduction guide я так писать не могу, 
// но должен писать:
auto c = Ok<int>(5); // T can not be deduced :(
```

Вопрос в том, как это переписать на С++14 или ниже? Чтоб я писал просто:

```
auto c = Ok("hello"s);  // T deduced as std::string
```

Но с произвольным типом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class T>
Ok<std::decay_t<T>> makeOk(T&& arg){
  return Ok<std::decay_t<T>>{std::forward<T>(arg)};
}

auto c = makeOk(5);
auto d = makeOk(std::make_unique<double>(6.7));
```

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Начал писать как комментарий, но не уложился в границы.</sup>

---

Ответ уже дан, но по большому счёту он был у Вас в вопросе, когда сравнивали конструктор с функцией.

Классическое решение - это как раз использование шаблонных `make-` функций. Всякие `make_pair`, `make_unique`, `make_shared` яркие тому примеры.

Дополнительно хочу заметить, что если тип `Ok` явно указывается  только при создании (через функцию-конструктор), то можно зайти немного с другого конца, нежели это сделал Виктор Смирнов в своём ответе, и в качестве имени порождающей функции использовать `Ok` вместо `makeOk`. А саму структуру переименовать, скажем, в `Ok_`. Может быть таким образом получится уменьшить количество мест, требующих изменения кода.